# How to access additional pivot field morphToMany?

Tags: laravel

I need to access additional field in pivot table.

junction table

```
id
additional
person_id
media_id
media_type
```

Artist model

```
 public function comic()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Person::class, 'media', 'media_people', 'media_id', 'person_id')->withPivot(['additional']);
    }
```

Controller

```
$artist = Artist::where('media_id', 1)->first();

echo json_encode( $artist->comic, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it using `pluck()` method of laravel collection

```
$artist = Artist::where('media_id', 1)->first();

echo json_encode( $artist->comic->pluck('pivot')->pluck('additional'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do for pivot data

```
$pivotData = $artist->comic->pivot;
```